# Use mac display separate from the computer?

Tags: screen, hdmi

I have a Mac with a relatively nice display. Is there some way to hook an external device (PS4 in this case) and use the monitor as the display for the PS4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an iMac 21"/27", yes you can use it as a display with the so called [Target Display mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3924).

You can enable it using the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> keyboard shortcut !

Comment: Do i need to perform that when the computer is booting, or just any time? And I obviously need an HDMI to Thunderbolt converter?

Comment: @iKiel2012 According to the linked support doc, you activate this after the computer has booted. And yes, you would need an [HDMI to Mini DisplayPort adapter](http://amzn.to/1dq8yqZ).

Comment: Of note: the 21" models did not support TDM until 2011.